# Multiple pop-ups using one click event repeated few times in Angular

Tags: angular, methods, popup, repeat

My problem is probably very easy to solve, but I've just started learning Angular and have no idea how it should look like. One of my components contains four a tags inside its .html file, looks like:

```
<a href="" (click)="doAfterClick()"></a>
...
...
<a href="" (click)="doAfterClick()"></a>
```

My code in this component's .ts file contains "doAfterClick()" method which opens a pop-up window with some text message. The idea is simple: depending on which link we click, we'll see another message in the pop-up, eg. Our array with messages is in the second component's .ts file and looks like:

```
messages = ["Message1", "Message2", "Message3", "Message4"];
```

When we click first link, pop-up window should contain "Message1", clicking second - we will see pop-up with "Message2".

In the second component's .html file, I created a paragraph which should contain my message from "messages" array:

```
<p *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index"> {{}} </p>
```

How can I connect my doAfterClick() method with messages array to display just one (correct) text message in pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
doAfterClick(index: number): void {
    return this.messages[index];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response - then what should I insert into {{}} in my paragraph to make it works?

Comment: {{ doAfterClick(i) }}